# Navigation problem with all browsers but ping message always has replies?

Tags: windows-xp, troubleshooting, ping, navigation

I had to fix a strange error on a remote computer using Windows Xp, the command `ping www.google.com -t` always has the replies, but navigating to www.google.com on Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Intenet Explorer does not show up the webpage.

The web page did show only one time after I tried to click on the F5 button for nearly 20 times :-s But after that, I just followed one link and it failed again.

The packages received from ping are not lost (100%). I even could do remote control using logmein.com service, could even chat by Gtalk to that computer.

What are the possible problems with that computer?

Can anyone show me the hints?

Thanks,

Comment: Is there any packet loss detected (less than 100% of replies) in `ping -t` output? What error exactly does the browser display?

Comment: there is completely no loss on any package, 100% packages received. The error display on the webpage is: "Webpage not found - error unknown Error Failed 2". Sorry I don't remember exactly the error message, because I did remote control on the other computer, now, it is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a firewall that blocks outgoing connections to TCP port 80. It may be installed on your computer or network gateway.

**EDIT**
After your corrections I still can only suggest that something is blocking port 80 (just because it's only one possible cause). Try to check the machine with an antimalware/antirootkit utility [AVZ](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2008/10/31/free-portable-and-powerful-avz-anti-viral-toolkit-from-kaspersky/) ([Download](http://z-oleg.com/avz4.zip)) and post the logfile somewhere.

Comment: hi whitequark, thanks for your response, but why sometimes the webpage appears, sometimes not. I guess it might be something else

Comment: You didn't wrote that pages DO sometimes appear in your question. Please, fix it: it is important for solving!

Comment: I edited the question :)

Comment: hi, thanks for your clarification, you know how funny it is when I am trying to solve the problem of accessing internet on a remote computer, now downloading is impossible as well :-s By the way, I am trying to go around by downloading in another computer and copying it by usb. Thank you again ;)